# Get List of all PC's in a local area network

Tags: vb.net, lan

The following code works intermittently. Why is that so? Sometimes result is blank,without any error.

```
    Imports System.DirectoryServices
    Public Class Form1

        Private Sub Button_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button.Click
            Dim result As String = ""            
            Dim domainEntry As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry("WinNT://CA")'CA is the workgroup
            domainEntry.Children.SchemaFilter.Add("Computer")

            For Each computer As DirectoryEntry In domainEntry.Children
                result = result & computer.Name & Environment.NewLine
            Next
            MsgBox(result)

        End Sub
End class
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows workgroups are a peer-to-peer arrangement, with no central server that controls who is on the workgroup. As such, the only way to list all the computers in the workgroup is to contact every computer in your network and check if they are part of the workgroup. That means each computer has to be powered on and connected to the same LAN.

My guess is that some computers are offline when you run that, some other reason that they cannot be contacted at the time you run it.

---

*Old answer:*

I'm not terribly familiar with using the WinNT provider, but see if you get different results with LDAP. This would find all computers on the domain (I assume "CA" is the name of your domain):

```
Dim ds As New DirectorySearcher(New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CA"), "(objectClass=computer)", New String() {"cn"})

Using src As SearchResultCollection = ds.FindAll()
    For Each sr As SearchResult In src
        result = result & sr.Properties("cn")(0) & Environment.NewLine
    Next
End Using
```

Comment: I get "The server is not operational." error , CA is a workgroup , not a domain. Any other methods?

Comment: Oh. You tagged `active-directory`. I will remove that tag then. My guess is that not all the computers are reachable each time you run it, so you will only get a list of computers that are.

Comment: i have more than 50 computers in the network.result is either all computers or nothing. "other reason that they cannot be contacted at the time you run it." - any reasons ?

Comment: Anything that would interrupt network communication. Other computers being asleep, off, or offline. The computer you're on being disconnected from the network. Firewalls, etc.